# Error handling in nested async functions in express.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to write a micro service to send a message to user to verify his phone number. I am working on the part of the micro service where sending a message to the endpoint with the correct verification code will trigger the code to add his phone number to Firebase. However, I would like to provide good error handling for user satisfaction and debugging purposes. I have read the express documentation. At first, I just threw an error in the async function, but I get a warning that unhanding promise exception will terminate the server with a non zero exit status in the future. If I handle the error in a catch block using express built in next or end function, the code does not terminate completely (even thought the documentation says it does). This causes the code to run my code that sends the user a success message (overwriting my previous error message). Even when I check to see the headers have been sent, it still does not stop the success response from overwriting my message.

The code works properly if you give it the correct information. What is important is that in the function validateVerificationCode throws an error to log and send to the client the correct error. When I trigger the endpoint that causes an error below I receive the information below.

Edit:
Below is what one might think is a possible solution. However, in express each async function that throws error must also catch errors. So the firebase query must catch the error.

```
   public async verifyVerification(
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
  ) {
    const { uid, verificationCode } = req.params;
    await this.validateVerificationCode(uid, verificationCode, res, next)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Verifying user sms verification code complete");
      })
      .catch(error => {
        res.status(500);
        res.json({ error: error });
      });

    res.json({ success: "success" });

  }

  public async validateVerificationCode(
    uid: string,
    verificationCode: string,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
  ) {
    const query = firestore.collectionGroup("PublicUser");

    const publicUserQuery = query.where("uid", "==", uid);
    publicUserQuery
      .limit(1)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot: any) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((documentSnapshot: any) => {
          const smsVerificationInfo = documentSnapshot.get(
            "smsVerificationInfo"
          );

          if (
            !smsVerificationInfo ||
            smsVerificationInfo.validUntil.seconds <
              Firestore.Timestamp.now().seconds
          ) {
            throw Error(
              "SMS has expired or does not exist. Please send new request"
            );
          } else if (smsVerificationInfo.verificationCode != verificationCode) {
            throw Error("Incorrect verification code");
          }

          documentSnapshot.ref.update({
            smsVerificationInfo: FieldValue.delete()
          });
          documentSnapshot.ref.set(
            {
              verifiedPhoneNumber: smsVerificationInfo.phoneNumber
            },
            { merge: true }
          );
        });
      })
  }





[start:dev] Server is listening on port 4000
[start:dev] Verifying user sms verification code complete
[start:dev] (node:77536) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
[start:dev]     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:535:11)
[start:dev]     at ServerResponse.header (/Users/rahmijamalpruitt/Documents/SideProjects/SonderPhoneMicroService/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
[start:dev]     at ServerResponse.send (/Users/rahmijamalpruitt/Documents/SideProjects/SonderPhoneMicroService/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
[start:dev]     at ServerResponse.json (/Users/rahmijamalpruitt/Documents/SideProjects/SonderPhoneMicroService/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
[start:dev]     at ServerResponse.send (/Users/rahmijamalpruitt/Documents/SideProjects/SonderPhoneMicroService/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
[start:dev]     at /Users/rahmijamalpruitt/Documents/SideProjects/SonderPhoneMicroService/dist/controllers/smsVerificationController.js:149:25
[start:dev]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
[start:dev] (node:77536) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
[start:dev] (node:77536) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Response {
   "status": 200,
   "success": "success"
}
```

Comment: in your `res`, don't forget to add `return`. It's will looks like this: `return res.send(...)`.

Comment: @TitusSutioFanpula that does not change anything.

Comment: I don't know what are you doing in the `catch()`, because in there, you're send request to the client, but you add `next` function in there.

Comment: You're not doing anything with two of the promises returned by Firestore API calls.  And since you didn't return a promise or use await at all inside `validateVerificationCode`, the await on that function call doesn't do anything helpful.  And I'm kind of confused why you aren't using async/await syntax uniformly in your code.

Comment: If you are confused on what next does, it is express built in function to handle error handling in async functions. in the documentation it says "If you pass anything to the next() function (except the string 'route'), Express regards the current request as being an error and will skip any remaining non-error handling routing and middleware functions"
if you are confused on why I send something before I call next, I want to be able to tell the client which error occurred before I tell express to stop executing code. @TitusSutioFanpula

Comment: @DougStevenson I was unaware firebase gave me two promises. Can you give me a link to an example.

Comment: All Firestore APIs that deal with data return a promise.  There are plenty of examples in the documentation.  I'm saying you're ignoring the promises from two of the three calls you're making.

Comment: I mean looks at your function/methods. In your `catch` on this function `validateVerificationCode`, you send `response` to the client and `next()`. Trust me, your `next` error in this function will be catch in this function: `verifyVerification` and then in there, you send `response` to the client again and in  there also, you pass the `next` function again. I don't know,if you create a error handler like this documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html, maybe you will send error again to the client. I don't know why it's twice or more. That's my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix the issue of having conflicting responses sent. I put the response handling out of the verifyVerification function entirely. I pass the response within the response.locals object.

```
router.get(
  "/verify/:uid/:verificationCode",
  async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    await smsVerificationController.verifyVerification(req, res, next);

    if (res.locals.error) {
      res.status(404).send({ error: res.locals.error.toString() });
    } else {
      res.status(200).json({
        success: "success"
      });
    }
  }
);
```

Also, I combine the function for better readability. However, this method will also work for deeply nested async functions.

```
public async verifyVerification(
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
  ) {
    const { uid, verificationCode } = req.params;

    const query = firestore
      .collectionGroup("PublicUser")
      .where("uid", "==", uid)
      .limit(1)
      .get();

    await query
      .then((snapshot: any) => {
        snapshot.forEach((documentSnapshot: any) => {
          const smsVerificationInfo = documentSnapshot.get(
            "smsVerificationInfo"
          );

          if (
            !smsVerificationInfo ||
            smsVerificationInfo.validUntil.seconds <
              Firestore.Timestamp.now().seconds
          ) {
            throw Error(
              "SMS has expired or does not exist. Please send new request"
            );
          } else if (smsVerificationInfo.verificationCode != verificationCode) {
            throw Error("Incorrect verification code");
          }

          documentSnapshot.ref.update({
            smsVerificationInfo: FieldValue.delete()
          });

          documentSnapshot.ref.set(
            {
              verifiedPhoneNumber: smsVerificationInfo.phoneNumber
            },
            { merge: true }
          );
        });
      })
      .catch((error: Error) => {
        res.locals.error = error;
        next(error);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

it throw the error because you are sending response twice.
first in `validateVerificationCode` and second in the `verifyVerification`.

you should not combine async and promise.

```
public async verifyVerification(req, res, next) {
    const {
        uid,
        verificationCode
    } = req.params;

    try {
        await this.validateVerificationCode(uid, req, res, next);
        res.status(200).json({
            success: 'success'
        });
    } catch(error => {
        res.status(404).send({ error });
    });
}


public async validateVerificationCode(uid, verificationCode, next) {
    const querySnapShot = await firestore.collectionGroup("PublicUser").where("uid", "==", uid).limit(1).get();

    querySnapShot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
        const smsVerificationInfo = documentSnapshot.get('smsVerificationInfo');
        const invalidTime = smsVerificationInfo.validUntil.seconds < Firestore.Timestamp.now().seconds;

        if(!smsVerificationInfo || invalidTime) {
            throw new Error('SMS has expired or does not exists. Please send new request');
        }

        if(smsVerificationInfo.verificationCode !== verificationCode) {
            throw new Error('Incorrect verification code');
        }


        documentSnapshot.ref.update({
            smsVerificationInfo: FieldValue.delete()
        });

        documentSnapshot.ref.set({
            verifiedPhoneNumber: smsVerificationInfo.phoneNumber
        }, { 
            merge: true 
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. As I stated previously, if I do not catch the error in the query snapshot in validateVerificationCode, I will receive unhandle promise warning. That's why, I was using next. I will agree that using next twice is overkill thank to @TitusSutioFanpula. Still, if I catch the promise in validateVerificationCode, it will not trigger the catch in verifyVerification. Causing it to send response.send({}|)